# DCOS marathon autoscaling failed--master url

Tags: mesos, autoscaling, marathon, dcos

I have a *DCOS* cluster running on azure and I have unlocked the *DCOS* ui by mapping it to my windows machine, so that I can access it on my localhost of windows-machine. I have a sample application running in marathon and I want to autoscale it using [this script](https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon-autoscale) I have given the parameters but it seems to be an error to get the `dcos-ca.crt`. 
In the parameters I have given the public *IP* of the master node and also tried with the private *IP* but nothing worked for me. 
I am not sure whether is it correct to give the public IP there because the actual *DCOS* ui is running on localhost of my windows machine.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have at least 2 public agents or change Marathon from "external" to "internal" if your communications work in internal network(not public)